# Событие прокрутки RecyclerView до конца

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как отловить момент, когда `RecyclerView` прокручен до конца?

Копал в сторону `onScrollListener`, но не уверен, что это именно то, что нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я у себя решил эту задачу при помощи `onScrollListener`, как-то так будет в итоге:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {

                    }

                }

                if (dy >= 5) {
                    loading = true;
                }


                if (dy < 0) {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

я делал это для загрузки данных при достижении конца и начала списка. Так же можно сделать интерфейс который подключать в адаптере, но у меня не получилось реализовать событие при достижении верха списка, поэтому остановился на этом слушателе. Надеюсь и вам поможет, если будут какие-то вопросы - спрашивайте, постараюсь помочь. Удачи :)